# how to configure highmaps of highcharts in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I am trying to use highmaps in ruby on rails where I am trying to use world countries but I couldn't find the world.js file in highchart lib folder

can someone help me how to configure highmaps in ruby on rails

Answer (score 0):

I found [worlds js](https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js) in one of the sample js fiddles,

Have a look [here](https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/data-class-ranges) for some more demo examples

Answer (score 0):

In order to use some map from Highcharts library, you need to attach it in your project. Here is the link to Highcharts Map Collection: http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/ and the documentation about how to use it correctly: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/map-collection .